# How can I create a product with a many-to-many relation using prisma where one of the tables has a unique constraint?

Tags: mysql, typescript, next.js, prisma

I have a prisma schema that I am trying to add new products to it. One of the tables is `Product`, which resembles a coffee product. A coffee product can contain multiple tasting notes, and it can contain multiple varieties. The other two tables are `TastingNote` and `Variety`, both of these tables can be associated to multiple products. Therefore, I would need to deal with a many-to-many relationship.

I have a unique constraint on the `TastingNote` and `Variety` table because I thought it would be best to not have duplicate values in these tables. I'm not sure if I'm right about adding these unique constraints but it's what is causing me some trouble right now.

My question is, how do I write the code in the request to not run into trouble trying to insert duplicate tasting notes or varieties when using Prisma? Do I have to first find the unique tasting notes by grabbing all of the tasting notes and seeing which ones are not yet in the database before doing my product creation and then do the same for the varieties? Or should I not have this unique constraint on these two columns in the first place?

Here is what my Prisma schema looks like currently:

```
model Brand {
    id                  Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
    name                String          @unique
    product             Product[]
}

model Country {
    id                  Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
    name                String          @unique
    continentId         Int             
    continent           Continent       @relation(fields: [continentId], references: [id])
    product             Product[]
    vendor              Vendor[]

    @@index([continentId])
}

model Continent {
    id                  Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
    name                String          @unique
    country             Country[]
}

model CurrencyCode {
    id                  Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
    code                String          @unique
    vendor              Vendor[]
}

model Vendor {
    id                  Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
    name                String          @unique
    countryId           Int
    country             Country         @relation(fields: [countryId], references: [id])
    currencyCodeId      Int
    currencyCode        CurrencyCode    @relation(fields: [currencyCodeId], references: [id])
    product             Product[]

    @@index([countryId])
    @@index([currencyCodeId])
}

model ProcessCategory {
    id                  Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
    name                String          @unique
    product             Product[]
}

model ProductType {
    id                  Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
    name                String          @unique

    product             Product[]
}

model TastingNote {
    id                  Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
    name                String          @unique
    product             Product[]
}

model Variety {
    id                  Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
    name                String          @unique
    product             Product[]
}


model Product {
    id                  Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
    brandId             Int
    brand               Brand           @relation(fields: [brandId], references: [id])
    countryOfOriginId   Int
    countryOfOrigin     Country         @relation(fields: [countryOfOriginId], references: [id])
    vendorId            Int
    vendor              Vendor          @relation(fields: [vendorId], references: [id])
    processCategoryId   Int
    processCategory     ProcessCategory @relation(fields: [processCategoryId], references: [id])
    productTypeId       Int
    productType         ProductType     @relation(fields: [productTypeId], references: [id])
    title               String
    weight              Int
    process             String
    productUrl          String          @unique
    imageUrl            String
    soldOut             Int             @db.TinyInt
    discoveredDateTime  DateTime
    handle              String
    price               Decimal
    decaf               Int             @db.TinyInt
    tastingNote         TastingNote[]
    variety             Variety[]

    @@index([brandId])
    @@index([countryOfOriginId])
    @@index([vendorId])
    @@index([processCategoryId])
    @@index([productTypeId])
    @@index([productUrl])
}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const key = 'name';

    const varietyRequestData = req.body.variety.map((x: string) => ({
      [key]: x,
    }));
    await prisma.variety.createMany({
      data: varietyRequestData,
      skipDuplicates: true,
    });

    const tastingNoteRequestData = req.body.tastingNote.map((x: string) => ({
      [key]: x,
    }));
    await prisma.tastingNote.createMany({
      data: tastingNoteRequestData,
      skipDuplicates: true,
    });

    await prisma.brand.upsert({
      where: {
        name: req.body.brand as string,
      },
      create: {
        name: req.body.brand as string,
      },
      update: {
        name: req.body.brand as string,
      },
    });

    const processCategoryQuery =
      req.body.process === ProcessCategory.Washed ||
      req.body.process === ProcessCategory.Natural ||
      req.body.process === ProcessCategory.Unknown
        ? req.body.process
        : ProcessCategory.Experimental;

    const processCategoryId = await prisma.processCategory.findUnique({
      select: {
        id: true,
      },
      where: {
        name: processCategoryQuery,
      },
    });

    const productTypeId = await prisma.productType.findUnique({
      select: {
        id: true,
      },
      where: {
        name: req.body.productType,
      },
    });

    const brandId = await prisma.brand.findUnique({
      select: {
        id: true,
      },
      where: {
        name: req.body.brand,
      },
    });

    const countryId = await prisma.country.findUnique({
      select: {
        id: true,
      },
      where: {
        name: req.body.countryOfOrigin,
      },
    });

    const vendor = await prisma.vendor.findUnique({
      where: {
        name: req.body.vendor,
      },
    });

    const productPostResponse = await prisma.product.create({
      data: {
        title: req.body.title,
        weight: req.body.weight,
        process: req.body.process,
        productUrl: req.body.productUrl,
        imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl,
        soldOut: req.body.soldOut,
        discoveredDateTime: req.body.discoveredDateTime,
        handle: req.body.handle,
        price: req.body.price,
        decaf: req.body.decaf,
        brandId: brandId!.id,
        vendorId: vendor!.id,
        processCategoryId: processCategoryId!.id,
        productTypeId: productTypeId!.id,
        countryOfOriginId: countryId!.id,
        tastingNote: ???,
        variety: ???,
      },
    });

    return res.status(200).json('Product added');
  }
}
```